# Android seekbar with custom thumb having dynamic text inside it

Tags: android, seekbar

I want to create android custom `SeekBar` having *thumb with text* inside it to show current seek position.

Here is my code:

```
SeekBar sb;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_seek_bar_activity);

    sb = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.slider);
    sb.setMax(100);
    sb.setProgress(10);
    BitmapDrawable bd = writeOnDrawable(R.drawable.star2, Double.toString(50));

    sb.setThumb(bd);

    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
        {
            int pos = sb.getProgress();
            double star = pos/(20.0);
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percent);
            tv.setText(Double.toString(star)+"%");
            BitmapDrawable bd = writeOnDrawable(R.drawable.star2, Double.toString(star));
            bd.setBounds(new Rect(0,0, 
                bd.getIntrinsicWidth(), 
                bd.getIntrinsicHeight()
            ));
            seekBar.setThumb(bd);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}   

public BitmapDrawable writeOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text){

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Paint paint = new Paint(); 
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);  
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
    paint.setTextSize(10); 

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, bm.getHeight()/2, paint);

    return new BitmapDrawable(bm);
}
```

but when I move thumb it goes to the beginning of the seek bar.
Does anyone have solution to move custom thumb with seekbar position?

Answer (score 15):

I use SeekBar to display a timer countdown in my app. Inside the timer thumb I show the current SeekBar progress number using the below code:

```
    SeekBar timerBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarTimer);
    if (timerBar != null) {
        timerBar.setMax((int) (Settings.countdownSeconds + 1));
        timerBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar timerBar, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.seek_thumb);
                Bitmap bmp = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
                String text = Integer.toString(timerBar.getProgress());
                Paint p = new Paint();
                p.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                p.setTextSize(14);
                p.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                int width = (int) p.measureText(text);
                int yPos = (int) ((c.getHeight() / 2) - ((p.descent() + p.ascent()) / 2));
                c.drawText(text, (bmp.getWidth()-width)/2, yPos, p);
                timerBar.setThumb(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp));
            }
        });
        timerBar.setProgress(0);
    }
```

The R.drawable.seek_thumb drawable is my thumb drawable.

Answer (score 4):

I got solution now, in `setBound()` method I was passing top left as `0`, that's why it is showing seek bar at beginning. After doing following change I got it works.

Call `setThumbPos()` method in `onProgressChanged()` event

```
public void setThumbPosition(SeekBar seekBar){
    int max = seekBar.getMax();

    int available = seekBar.getWidth() - seekBar.getPaddingLeft() - seekBar.getPaddingRight();
    float scale = max > 0 ? (float) seekBar.getProgress() / (float) max : 0;

    //scale = 1;
    int pos = sb.getProgress();
    double star = pos/(20.0);

    BitmapDrawable bd = writeOnDrawable(R.drawable.star2, Double.toString(star));

    int thumbWidth = bd.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int thumbHeight = bd.getIntrinsicHeight();
    //available -= thumbWidth;

    int thumbPos = (int) (scale * available);
    if(thumbPos <= 0+thumbWidth){
        thumbPos += (thumbWidth/2);
    }else if(thumbPos >= seekBar.getWidth()-thumbWidth){
        thumbPos -= (thumbWidth/2);
    }

    bd.setBounds(new Rect(thumbPos,0, 
            thumbPos+bd.getIntrinsicWidth(), 
        bd.getIntrinsicHeight()
    ));

    seekBar.setThumb(bd);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percent);
    tv.setText(Double.toString(star)+"%");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using this simple solution.  Its probably not *as* high-performance as say a proper custom SeekBar, however its really easy to plug into an existing layout, and use any label or other view on top of the SeekBar thumb.

```
protected void positionThumbLabel(SeekBar seekBar, TextView label)
{
  Rect tr = seekBar.getThumb().getBounds();
  label.setWidth(tr.width());
  label.setX(tr.left + seekBar.getPaddingLeft());
}
```

With some minor changes you can position an overlay relative to the center of the thumb:

```
protected void positionThumbOverlayCenter(SeekBar seekBar, View overlay)
{
  Rect tr = seekBar.getThumb().getBounds();
  overlay.setX(tr.centerX() - (overlay.getWidth() * 0.5f) + seekBar.getPaddingLeft());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pick a solution that match your situation here: http://www.helptouser.com/code/10722746-add-dynamic-text-over-android-seekbar-thumb.html

Comment: The link is dead. Can you provide an alternative?