# Android seekbar custom thumb stuck at start

Tags: android, seekbar, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-4.2-jelly-bean

**JAVA**

```
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            app.iMeter = progress;

            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.slider_pad_2x).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

            float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            float x = (int) (17 * scale + 0.5f);
            int y = (int) ((b.getHeight()/2-3) * scale + 0.5f);

            if(seekBar.getProgress() > 9) {
                x = (int) (14 * scale + 0.5f);
            }
            if(seekBar.getProgress() > 99) {
                x = (int) (11 * scale + 0.5f);
            }

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
            canvas.drawText(""+progress, x, y, paint);
            BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(b);

            bd.setBounds(0, 0, bd.getIntrinsicWidth(), bd.getIntrinsicHeight());

            seekBar.setThumb(bd);
        }
```

**XML**

```
        <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/slider_background_2x"
                android:max="200"
                android:paddingLeft="17dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:progress="0"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/transparant_dot"
                android:thumb="@drawable/slider_pad_2x" />
```

I'm testing it on 2 different version of android devices:

- Android 2.3.6
- Android 4.2.2

On 4.2.2 it works as it should. The drawable is shown with the progress value drawn over it. On 2.3.6 the thumb is stuck at the beginning. The value on the thumb does change when I try to move it, but it remains stuck.

I can remove setBounds and it still works on 4.2.2, but on 2.3.6 the thumb will completely dissapear when I touch it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am too having the same issue. Works fine in Android versions > 4.0, but not working in 2.3.x

Comment: Hi Pim, Me to facing same issue it not working on android 2.3.6. Did you resolved this issue. If you resolved issue, Please help how can i resolve this issue

Comment: Hey Murali, yes I resolved the issue but I do not have access to the code anymore (switched job)... but it is possible. If you find a solution please add it as answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like on Android < 2.3.x the bounds of the thumb are just updated when the progress changed but not when calling `setThumb()`. That's why you have to call `setBounds()` on the Drawable before setting it as the Thumb to make it visible at all. But when you call

```
bd.setBounds(0, 0, bd.getIntrinsicWidth(), bd.getIntrinsicHeight());
```

you also set the position and therefore lock it at the beginning.
On Android > 4.0 `setBounds()` is called when calling `setThumb()` in this case so calling `setBounds()` on your drawable doesn't do anything.

To solve this you could give the right bounds by calculating them yourself. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12705633) for an example.

I had my own class which extended SeekBar so calling `super.onSizeChanged()` after setting the thumb solved it for me.

Comment: Thank you! It works for me. I just called super.onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), getWidth(), getHeight()); After setting new thumb.