# Custom seek bar with thumb and progressDrawable

Tags: android, seekbar

I try to customize seek bar like below

[image]

```
But problem is that 
-thumb image not set with text 
-thumb position can not set above seekbar.
-android:progressDrawable should not repeat as below
```

[image]
 My Code is as below:

```
         <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/volume_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="20"                
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/bar"
            android:secondaryProgress="0"                
            android:thumb="@drawable/greenarrow" />
```

Comment: use another view for the green arrow and just move it by changing its margin according the seekbar with an invisible thumb

Comment: thnaks for answer . can u explain how to move custom view with thumb?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried doing this, but I ran into problems with response time the way I did it. Having to move the margins took a lot of processing power and time.  It was close to 400-500ms.  So I had to remove it.

However, here are the steps I took:
First, I would suggest creating a frame layout to hold both the SeekBar and a TextView.  Then, depending on the percentage of the progress bar, you can set the TextViews layout property margins.
Does that make sense?

If you would like specific code, I can get that to you, but google does pretty good too. :)

**Option B:** [Android seekbar with custom thumb having dynamic text inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674477/android-seekbar-with-custom-thumb-having-dynamic-text-inside-it?rq=1)